# How to create a varying mask to compare a string of bits?

Tags: c++

**Problem:** Given a string of bits, like this:

```
1) 1011
2) 0011
3) 1101
4) 1101
```

I want to compare all the bits except the 4th (to see if they are equal. For example, removing the 4th bit, would make the first and the second equal). Then the same but removing the 3rd bit and so on. For that, I can think of a mask (to "remove" each bit). That mask should go:

```
1) 0111
2) 1011
3) 1101
4) 1110
```

One way I have seen to do this, but doesn't make much sense to me (although it works) is (the part that I don't understand and seems "random" is the function):

```
unsigned long symbolMask;
int numberOfSetBits(int i) {
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}

int bitNumber = 4;
unsigned long maxBits = 1 << bitNumber;
for (int i = bitNumber; i > 0; ) {
    --i;
    for (symbolMask = 0; symbolMask < maxBits; ++symbolMask)
        if (numberOfSetBits(symbolMask) == i){
    
            // At this point, symbolMask is the correct mask. In each iteration, the output is:
            // 1) 0111
            // 2) 1011
            // 3) 1101
            // 4) 1110
            // (...)
            cout << symbolMask << endl;
    
        }
}
```

As I said, that code works but I think there should be a better way of doing it.

Comment: Please don't post the identical question again. You can edit the original to make the question clearer. It will be reopened if you fix the problems there. You're not going to have a different result if you just post the same question again.

Comment: Well at least now I understand the question.

Comment: @john It's still unclear to me, but you should vote to reopen the original question.